# Обработка сокетов в ASP.NET Core. Перевод на хостинг IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Есть проект, написанный на ASP.NET Core 3.1 который переехал на .NET 6 (MVC).
В нем есть Kestrel который слушает определенный порт и при новом соединении внешних клиентов с сервером (клиенты представляют себе устройства которые по IP на определенный порт стучаться и передают состояние), может быть сотни подключений, попадает в handler через UseConnectionHandler

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.ListenAnyIP(7890, _o => _o.UseConnectionHandler<HeadConnectionHandler>());
                    options.ListenAnyIP(80);
                });
                
                webBuilder.UseIISIntegration();
                webBuilder
                    .UseSockets(_s => { _s.NoDelay = false; })                        
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();                    
            });
```

Есть обычный порт 80 - по которому работает обычный сайт.
Проект крутится на виндовом сервере, через публикацию переносимой версии и зависимости от платформы. Запускается через exe в режиме автономности, при запуске exe файла сборки, все работает.

Публикую в IIS, сайт запускается, но прослушивание порта и переход в HeadConnectionHandler - не происходит.
Как правильно настроить работу сервиса, чтобы работал код аналогичный в месте где используется Kestrel?

UPD. I need help :)

Comment: Просто убрать `UseKestrel` и добавьте собранный сайт в IIS, все..., не?

Comment: Если уберу, то как будет происходить прослушка порта и обработка handlera для новых подключений, не совсем понимаю

Comment: [Kestrel в роли прокси](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/when-to-use-a-reverse-proxy). Когда вы публикуете приложение в IIS, Nginx, Apache, за порт ваш сайт не отвечает, он лишь обрабатывает команды, которые ему дает конкретный сервер, а уже сам сервер отвечает за порт, и прочую информацию для "связи" с вашим сайтом. Так что просто уберите совсем `.UseKestrel`, пусть приложение само разберется как ему жить, далее добавьте в IIS сайт, в нем укажите путь, привязки (порт), ну и у "Пула" укажите "Без управляемого кода", а, еще Hosting Bundle не забудьте.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, буду пробовать.
Мне не совсем прозрачно становится обработка пакетов из вне и просто работа сайта. Например, на порт 7890 стучатся клиенты и их обрабатывает kestrel в headConnectionHanldler, также сайт работает как обычный сайт(он по факту mvc) по другому порту и в случае если Kestrel убираю, не совсем прозрачно становится как будет все это управляться...

Comment: Ну почему, все будет тоже самое, только у вас появляется еще одно связующее звено в виде IIS, который первым получает запрос, а потом отправляет его в ваше приложение, где все также будет обработано как и раньше, будут также использоваться контроллеры, все его маршруты, и так далее, вы просто часть обязанностей Kestrel'а передаете IIS, все.

Comment: Все равно не получается .... iis запускается, но в handler не заходит

Answer (score 0):

Вызов `UseIISIntegration` делает, упрощённо говоря, следующее:

1. Проверяет переменные окружения ASPNETCORE_*, на наличие
2. Если их нет - не делает ничего
3. Если они есть - то затирает настройки конечных точек Kestrel, заставляя его слушать указанный в переменных окружения порт, а также применяет ещё несколько настроек

Если вам надо открыть дополнительный порт с отдельными настройками - это можно сделать примерно так:

1. Убедитесь что вы создаёте ваш хост либо веб-приложение без настроек по умолчанию, чтобы никто не вызвал `UseIISIntegration()`;
2. Загляните в исходники `UseIISIntegration()` чтобы повторить всё то что оно делает - но вручную и без переопределения настроек Kestrel;
3. Также не забудьте использовать переданные вам переменные окружения в настройках Kestrel;
4. Когда будете добавлять StartupFilter с вспомогательными мидлварями - не забудьте исключить из его обработки запросы с дополнительной конечной точки (отличить одну конечную точку от другой можно с помощью коллекции Features, которую вы можете менять в вашем HeadConnectionHandler).

Но на самом деле это всё бесполезно, и знаете почему? Потому что IIS отвечает за запуск вашего процесса, и он запустит его только когда придёт запрос на порт 80. То есть, насколько я понял вашу архитектуру, пока первый пользователь не зайдёт на сайт - никакие устройства не смогут передать вам никакое состояние.

Это вообще не то поведение которое нужно в таких случаях!

---

Как сделать правильно.

Вариант 1:

Откажитесь от прямой публикации в IIS, и запускайте ваш сервер как системную службу, слушающую 127.0.0.1 на нестандартном порту. IIS можно настроить как прокси-сервер без автоматических интеграций.

Вариант 2.

Откажитесь от прямой публикации в IIS, и запускайте ваш сервер как системную службу, слушающую 80й порт напрямую. IIS выкиньте нафиг.

Вариант 3.

Откажитесь от Windows, настройте интеграцию с systemd и запускайте ваш сервер как systemd unit на Linux. Это позволит сэкономить на хостинге если вы хоститесь в облаке.

Comment: Наверно не совсем поняли или я вас
На текущий момент это один проект, который и слушает нестандартный порт, на него шлют пакеты с данными устройства, внешние грубо говоря http клиенты, когда пакет приходит он обрабатывается в 
handler (UseConnectionHandler -> HeadConnectionHandler), а с другой стороны у него открыт условно стандартный порт на котором работает сайт 
весь проект mvc
понятно, что лучше тот же листенер сервис вынести в отдельный микросервис, итд итп, но такой возможности нет.
Проблема в том, чтобы на сервере не запускать локально exe  файл, а  настроить  iis

Comment: @DenisIvanov вы не сказали ничего нового, мой ответ не изменился